# React Js - Clicking on child radio button hides the current and parent selection

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a radio buttons based on some conditions. If the parent radio button is checked, then show the sub elements (Which is a child radio button). The condition works fine. But when I select anything from the child Radio button, it is hiding the current selection and making the parent to be deselected.

I am new to react and can someone help me fix this issue. Here is the link I am trying https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-part6-form-with-inputs-checkbox-radio-button-dro-9nknlf?embed=1&file=Form.js.

In this example, When I choose 'User A', it shows the child  'User A child 1'. If I click on the Child 1, it is getting hidden.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <input
            disabled={disableuserA}
            type="radio"
            name="user"
            value="userA"
            **checked={selected === 'userA' || selected === 'test'}**
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          userA
```

and

```
    <div aria-hidden={selected !== 'userA' && selected !== 'test' ? true : false}>
```

Comment: Thanks, Rohit and Binoy for the pointers. It's working now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line of the code

```
<div aria-hidden={selected !== 'userA' ? true : false}>
```

When you click on the child radio button the value of `selected` become `test`

But according to your condition `selected !== 'userA' ? true : false` you are telling it to hide the checkbox if value of `selected` is not equal to `userA`

A better way to solve this problem would be to create another useState to check if a parent element is checked and render child elements according to it.